# How can I make this shape in css?

Tags: css

[image]

I'm going to write in the form, when it's one word.

[image]

But if it's more than two letters, I'll write like this.

Can I make this shape?

Comment: Hi, what exactly you wanna do? Do you want the css of this shape or the way you can recognize the one or two letters?

Comment: I want recognize the one or two letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
count{
  position:relative;
  color:white;
  margin:0.5em;
}
count:before{
  content:'';
  min-width:1em;
  position:absolute;
  left:-0.5em;
  right:-0.5em;
  top:-0.2em;
  bottom:-0.2em;
  background-color:blue;
  z-index:-4;
  border-radius:1em;
}
```

```html
<count>100</count>

<count>5</count>
<count>100.000</count>
```

Try this

Comment: Why did you try to delete it?

Comment: 100 and 100.000 are `more than two letters`. In this case a 99+ should be shown. Problem: 100 shows 100 and 100.000 shows 100.000.

Comment: It's fine. I will send '99+' from the server if I have more than 99. It is not necessary to treat with css.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this kind of shape using `border radius`.

Get more info.

[Border Radius](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2 class="number">5</h2>

<h2 class="text">99+</h2>
```

and use this css

```
.number{
  background:blue;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:5px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px;
  color:white;
}

.text{
  background:blue;
  border-radius:25px;
  padding:25px;

  text-align:center;
  line-height:25px;
  color:white;
}
```